# How to Add an icon on the titlebar?

Tags: vba

Below code working fine to Minimize userform to task bar, but don't know how to insert image work. Getting error on `Sub AddIcon(myForm)`

```
Sub AddIcon(myForm)

    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hWnd As LongPtr
        Dim lngRet As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hWnd As Long
        Dim lngRet As Long
    #End If

    Dim hIcon As Long
    'hIcon = Sheet1.Image1.Picture.Handle
    hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, myForm.Caption)
    lngRet = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, ByVal hIcon)
    lngRet = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, ByVal hIcon)
    lngRet = DrawMenuBar(hWnd)
End Sub

Sub AddMinimizeButton()
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hWnd As Long
    #End If

    hWnd = GetActiveWindow
    Call SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, _
                       GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) Or _
                       WS_MINIMIZEBOX)
    Call SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, _
                      SWP_FRAMECHANGED Or _
                      SWP_NOMOVE Or _
                      SWP_NOSIZE)
End Sub

 Sub AppTasklist(myForm)
'Add this userform into the Task bar
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim WStyle As LongPtr
        Dim Result As LongPtr
        Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim WStyle As Long
        Dim Result As Long
        Dim hWnd As Long
    #End If

    hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, myForm.Caption)
    WStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
    WStyle = WStyle Or WS_EX_APPWINDOW
    Result = SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, _
                          SWP_NOMOVE Or _
                          SWP_NOSIZE Or _
                          SWP_NOACTIVATE Or _
                          SWP_HIDEWINDOW)
    Result = SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WStyle)
    Result = SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, _
                          SWP_NOMOVE Or _
                          SWP_NOSIZE Or _
                          SWP_NOACTIVATE Or _
                          SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
End Sub
```

Comment: What error on which code line? Did ou also have the necessary API functions (FindWindow, GetWindowLongPtr, SetWindowPos etc.)?

Comment: Where from did you take this piece of code?

Comment: Got code from same forum , do not know how to insert icon in excel file .
it is working fine to minimize userForum , but showing Excel icon.
Need to change icon , getting error on "hIcon = Sheet1.Image1.Picture.Handle" l

Comment: Are there in your Sheet1 an ActiveX Image control named "Image1", having a picture on it, to feed the code with the necessary picture handler? I can see the line doing that is commented... Only because it returned an error? But you did not answer my above question. Did you also copy the necessary API functions?

Comment: no i dont have"Image1" in my Sheet1 , but i need to add it .
I try with insert object but it dosent work .
how to add "Image1" in Sheet1? kindly help .
Sorry for stupid question but need help.

Comment: Go in 'Developer' Tab (if enabled), press 'Design' button (in 'Controls' area), press 'Insert' and select 'Image (ActiveX control)`. Then go on the sheet and set its dimensions moving the cursor. Right click on the control -> Properties -> click on 'Picture' property, press the three dots icon to open a browse window and select a picture from your computer. If 'Developer' tab is not enabled, right click on ribbon, choose 'Customize the Ribbon...' and check 'Developer' in the right side (Customize the Ribbon:).

Comment: You did not say anything about the necessary API function declarations...

Comment: Now added image1 in sheet1 with help of insert and design tool in developer tab.
when user form is open it showing icon now , but after minimize showing excel icon only .

Comment: Where the icon in discussion is shown? In the title bar, as you asked? I never needed such a icon. I only tried helping you looking to the code... What Excel version do you use? Then, if the above supposition is correct, what do you mean by "after minimize"? After minimize of what? Can you minimize a user form? Are you talking about the taskbar icon?

Comment: Really thanks for Help and your time.. Excel 2016 64 bit ...When userform normal open it is showing icon after minimize to taskbar not showing icon.

Comment: Now it's working....really thanks for help. Just use other code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kLZd00bKadtNdnOZIY49PRxpl5cp624-/view?usp=sharing